# How to append output to the end of a text file

Tags: bash, shell

How do I append the output of a command to the end of a text file?

Answer (score 953):

Use `>>` instead of `>` when directing output to a file:

```
your_command >> file_to_append_to
```

If `file_to_append_to` does not exist, it will be created.

**Example:**

```
$ echo "hello" > file
$ echo "world" >> file
$ cat file 
hello
world
```

Comment: The problem is that `echo` removes the newlines from the string. How do you append to a file a string which contains newlines?

Comment: @TimothySwan, I believe with the -e option.

Comment: echo does not remove newlines from the string.  If you fail to properly quote the argument, then the shell will split the string and pass arguments to echo and echo never even sees the newlines.

Comment: `echo` may not expand escape sequences. Use `printf` instead

Comment: @Pmpr note that `echo` is not part of the _solution_, it is only part of the _example_ I typed, and there are no escape sequences in the example.

Answer (score 177):

To `append` a file use  `>>`

```
echo "hello world"  >> read.txt   
cat read.txt     
echo "hello siva" >> read.txt   
cat read.txt
```

then the output should be

```
hello world   # from 1st echo command
hello world   # from 2nd echo command
hello siva
```

To `overwrite` a file use  `>`

```
echo "hello tom" > read.txt
cat read.txt
```

then the out put is

`hello tom`

Answer (score 81):

You can use the >> operator. This will append data from a command to the end of a text file.

To test this try running:

```
echo "Hi this is a test" >> textfile.txt
```

Do this a couple of times and then run:

```
cat textfile.txt
```

You'll see your text has been appended several times to the textfile.txt file.

Answer (score 60):

Use `command >> file_to_append_to` to append to a file.

For example `echo "Hello" >> testFile.txt`

**CAUTION:** if you only use a single `>` you will overwrite the contents of the file. To ensure that doesn't ever happen, you can add `set -o noclobber` to your `.bashrc`.

This ensures that if you accidentally type `command > file_to_append_to` to an existing file, it will alert you that the file exists already. Sample error message: `file exists: testFile.txt`

Thus, when you use `>` it will only allow you to create a new file, not overwrite an existing file.

Answer (score 52):

Using ***tee*** with option **-a (--append)** allows you to append to multiple files at once and also to use **sudo** (very useful when appending to protected files). Besides that, it is interesting if you need to use other shells besides bash, as not all shells support the > and >> operators

```
echo "hello world" | sudo tee -a output.txt
```

This [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/408340/is-there-any-significance-to-using-tee) has good answers about tee

Comment: This is the best way to append something with a new line.

Comment: was looking for a way to append to protected files and this solves it

Comment: The addition of `sudo` is irrelevant here, and possibly dangerously misleading.

Answer (score 28):

Use the `>>` operator to append text to a file.

Answer (score 24):

I often confuse the two. Better to remember through their output:

### > for Overwrite

```
$ touch someFile.txt
$ echo ">" > someFile.txt
$ cat someFile.txt
  >
$ echo ">" > someFile.txt
$ cat someFile.txt
  >
```

### >> for Append

```
$ echo ">" > someFile.txt
$ cat someFile.txt
  >
$ echo ">" >> someFile.txt
$ cat someFile.txt
  >>
```

Answer (score 15):

for the whole question:

```
cmd >> o.txt && [[ $(wc -l <o.txt) -eq 720 ]] && mv o.txt $(date +%F).o.txt
```

this will append 720 lines (30*24) into o.txt and after will rename the file based on the current date.

Run the above with the cron every hour, or

```
while :
do
    cmd >> o.txt && [[ $(wc -l <o.txt) -eq 720 ]] && mv o.txt $(date +%F).o.txt
    sleep 3600
done
```

Answer (score 15):

I would use printf instead of echo because it's [more reliable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) and processes formatting such as new line `\n` properly.

This example produces an output similar to echo in previous examples:

```
printf "hello world"  >> read.txt   
cat read.txt
hello world
```

However if you were to replace printf with echo in this example, echo would treat \n as a string, thus ignoring the intent

```
printf "hello\nworld"  >> read.txt   
cat read.txt
hello
world
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest you do two things:

1. Use `>>` in your shell script to append contents to particular file. The filename can be fixed or using some pattern.
2. Setup a hourly cronjob to trigger the shell script

Answer (score 8):

For example your file contains :

```
 1.  mangesh@001:~$ cat output.txt
    1
    2
    EOF
```

if u want to append at end of file then ---->remember spaces between 'text' >> 'filename'

```
  2. mangesh@001:~$ echo somthing to append >> output.txt|cat output.txt 
    1
    2
    EOF
    somthing to append
```

And to overwrite contents of file :

```
  3.  mangesh@001:~$ echo 'somthing new to write' > output.tx|cat output.tx
    somthing new to write
```

Comment: This is misleading in many details. Spaces are *not* important and piping an empty output to `cat` is ... just completely wacky. (It's empty because you just redirected standard output to a file.)

Answer (score 5):

In Linux, You can use `cat` command  to append file content to another file

> `cat fileName_1.txt >> fileName_2.txt`

In the previous command you will append content of `fileName_1.txt` to `fileName_2.txt`.

In Windows OS you can use `type` command

> `type fileName_1.txt >> fileName_2.txt`

See this gif image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While all of these answers are technically correct that appending to a file with `>>` is generally the way to go, note that if you use this in a loop when for example parsing/processing a file and append each line to the resulting file, this might be much slower then you would expect.

A faster alternative might be this:

```sh
stringBuilder=""
while read -r line; do
  # $'\n' prints a newline so we don't have to know what special chars the string contains
  stringBuilder+="$line"$'\n'
done < "myFile.txt"
echo "$stringBuilder" > $file
```

WARNING: you are reading all lines into memory; memory is a limited resource, so don't go doing this for gigantic files.