# How to create a file under /tmp/stage2/ named system.info?

Tags: linux, shell

How can I create a file under `/tmp/stage2/` named `system.info`? What are the commands to use? Also how do I append the following information to the file?

- The full hostname
- The current date
- The load of the system

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append output to the end of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207573/how-to-append-output-to-the-end-of-a-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you show do like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

MYSYS_PATH="/tmp/stage2/system.info"
mkdir -p /tmp/stage2
hostname > $MYSYS_PATH
date >>$MYSYS_PATH
cat cat /proc/loadavg >>$MYSYS_PATH
```